# Special Characters rendering on Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, rendering

Recently a customer notified me of some special characters not rendering correctly.
If this was always the case, i'm not sure exactly, thought not.

The problem lies here:
http://waterforum.net/

On IE/Opera/FireFox, it shows the special characters correctly.

However, on Chrome and my SGS3 for example, it does not.

1. What i've tried,
2. Forcing UTF8 due to htaccess
3. DOCType
4. Charset declaration
5. Checking Database tables

Do you guys have a clue?
Or is it just a bug?

Comment: What os are you running? Try to find a font which supports the characters and then use Font-Faces to import and use it. http://www.fontsquirrel.com/ has many free-to-use fonts, many fonts also have ready font-face packages.

Comment: I'm running XP on this one(work computer) however, my boss has Vista and it fails also. Same on W7, just checked.

Comment: Just checked on Ubuntu 12.10, it worked in Firefox, but not in Chrome Beta. The characters rendered incorrectly really do look like as if they are due to incorrect character encoding. I checked your headers and ISO-8859-1 is the character encoding. Try setting it to UTF-8 in your headers using PHP header function, like so: header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

Comment: Can i ask where you saw that? WC3 is saying it's UTF8 however, it's still incorrect.

Comment: In your headers: Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried changing the UA-string to Firefox Windows from Chrome default.

By default in Chrome this is the `Content-type`:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

Characters are then displayed incorrectly.

When I switch to Firefox UA, the `Content-type` is changed to:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

This problem might lay hidden in the fact that Chrome sends `Accept-encoding` but as Chrome displays it correctly with another UA, this is most likely not the case.

Try and see what happens with different UA-strings, the use of UA-strings to deliver different content is highly discouraged because of problems like these.